# Better multithreaded use of Python subprocess.Popen & communicate()?

Tags: python, multithreading, pipe, subprocess

I'm running multiple commands which may take some time, in parallel, on a Linux machine running Python 2.6.

So, I used `subprocess.Popen` class and `process.communicate()` method to parallelize execution of mulitple command groups and capture the output at once after execution.

```
def run_commands(commands, print_lock):
    # this part runs in parallel.
    outputs = []
    for command in commands:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, close_fds=True)
        output, unused_err = proc.communicate()  # buffers the output
        retcode = proc.poll()                    # ensures subprocess termination
        outputs.append(output)
    with print_lock: # print them at once (synchronized)
        for output in outputs:
            for line in output.splitlines():
                print(line)
```

At somewhere else it's called like this:

```
processes = []
print_lock = Lock()
for ...:
    commands = ...  # a group of commands is generated, which takes some time.
    processes.append(Thread(target=run_commands, args=(commands, print_lock)))
    processes[-1].start()
for p in processes: p.join()
print('done.')
```

The expected result is that each output of a group of commands is displayed at once while execution of them is done in parallel.

But from the second output group (of course, the thread that become the second is changed due to scheduling indeterminism), it begins to print without newlines and adding spaces as many as the number of characters printed in each previous line and input echo is turned off -- the terminal state is "garbled" or "crashed". (If I issue `reset` shell command, it restores normal.)

At first, I tried to find the reason from handling of `'\r'`, but it was not the reason. As you see in my code, I handled it properly using `splitlines()`, and I confirmed that with `repr()` function applied to the output.

I think the reason is concurrent use of pipes in `Popen` and `communicate()` for stdout/stderr. I tried `check_output` shortcut method in Python 2.7, but no success. Of course, the problem described above does not occur if I serialize all command executions and prints.

Is there any better way to handle `Popen` and `communicate()` in parallel?

Comment: `.communicate()` ensures process completion due to it calls `Popen.wait()`. But `proc.poll()` does not ensure process completion. It returns `None` if the process is not finished. For example on Linux it calls `waitpid(pid, WNOHANG)`. The docs for `WNOHANG` say: "The waitpid() function does not suspend execution of the calling thread if status is not immediately available for one of the child processes specified by pid." http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/waitpid.3.asp

Comment: Here's the script that run all processes in parallel and group output by process group preserving the order within group https://gist.github.com/717467

Comment: Thanks for Sebastian, but your solution did not solve the problem completely. It seems to be a bug in Python's subprocess implementation and its synchronization. I added the final result as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A final result inspired by the comment from J.F.Sebastian.

http://bitbucket.org/daybreaker/kaist-cs443/src/247f9ecf3cee/tools/manage.py

It seems to be a Python bug.

Comment: You could replace `None` by `group_id` on line 124 and remove `time.sleep(0.5)`. `print_stdout()` is written under the assumption that `queue.put((FLAG_GROUP_SIZE, group_id, len(command_group))` may be called at any time before/during/after any processes started/run/finished. I don't understand how Python bugs you mentioned on the line 122 are related to "garbled" output in a terminal. The idea of my fix is to start/wait for processes in the main thread. IO threads and `t.join()` I think could be run in yet another thread; I left them in the main thread for simplicity.

Comment: btw,  `outputs[group_id][command_id]` is expected to contain *all* output for a given command, so `output_queue.put((group_id, command_id, line))` in `read_stdout()` is invalid if you'd like to see more than one line of output per process.

Comment: Yes, I have catched that your idea is start/wait for processes in the main thread and `queue.put((FLAG_GROUP_SIZSE, ...))` may be called at anytime during process execution. But if I don't put `time.sleep`, it shows garbled output randomly.

Comment: You program was to place the whole output of a process into a single dictionary value, but I wanted to print line by line using hostname for readability (because some commands may generate multiple lines of output). That's why I modified `read_stdout` to use `splitlines`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is clear what run_commands needs to  be actually doing, but it seems to be simply doing a poll on a subprocess, ignoring the return-code and continuing in the loop. When you get to the part where you are printing output, how could you know the sub-processes have completed?

Comment: That's ensured by `poll()` method. It returns immediately if the return code is already available (which means the subprocess finished during `communicate()`) or wait until it's finished.

Comment: So, there's no difference between -

"
Popen.poll() - Check if child process has terminated. Set and return returncode attribute."

AND

"Popen.wait() - Wait for child process to terminate. Set and return returncode attribute." ?

Comment: Python manual says `wait()` causes deadlock if called after `communicate()`. The point of my question is not the return code or subprocess termination -- multithreaded subprocess garbles the terminal outputs after finishing of the first thread which got the control first.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I guess I missed the fact that communicate() itself waits for the process to terminate.

Answer (score 0):

In your example code I noticed your use of:

```
for line in output.splitlines():
```

to address partially the issue of  " **/r** " ; use of

```
for line in output.splitlines(True):
```

would have been helpful.