# Multiple port scans using external tool, subprocess.Popen and threads

Tags: python, subprocess, python-2.4

I am using a port scanner to scan my subnet. The port scanner unfortunately can scan one port of only one host at a time. Also the scanner has a 1 sec timeout for unreachable hosts. The scanner(being an outside program) has to be run from subprocess.Popen() and to speed it up - so that I may send multiple probes while some previous ones are waiting for replies- I use threads. The problem comes up for a complete /24 subnet scan with large number of threads. SOme of the actually open ports are displayed as closed. I suspect somehow the output gets garbled. Note that this does not occur if I scan fewer hosts or one host at a time

The following code is my attempt to create a pool of threads which take an IP address and run 'sequential' port scan for defined port. Once all specified ports are scanned, it picks up next IP from the list.

```
        while True:
            if not thread_queue.empty():
                try:
                    hst = ip_iter.next()
                except StopIteration:
                    break
                m=thread_queue.get()
                l=ThreadWork(self,hst,m)
                l.start()
        while open_threads != 0:
            pass
```

Where this fragment sets up thread queue

```
        thread_list = [x for x in range(num_threads)]
        for t in thread_list:
            thread_queue.put(str(t))
        ip_iter=iter(self.final_target)
```

In the ThreadWork function I keep a tab of open threads(since thread_queue.empty proved to be unreliable, I had to use this crude way)

```
class ThreadWork(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,i,hst,thread_no):
        global open_threads
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.host = hst
        self.ptr = i
        self.t = thread_no
        lock.acquire()
        open_threads = open_threads + 1
        lock.release() 

    def run(self):
        global thread_queue
        global open_threads
        global lock
        user_log.info("Executing sinfp for IP Address : %s"%self.host)
        self.ptr.result.append(SinFpRes(self.host,self.ptr.init_ports,self.ptr.all_ports,self.ptr.options,self.ptr.cf))
        lock.acquire()
        open_threads = open_threads - 1
        lock.release()
        thread_queue.put(self.t)
```

The call to SinFpRes creates a result object for one IP and initiate sequential scanning of ports for that IP only.
The actual scan per port is as shown

```
        com_string = '/usr/local/sinfp/bin/sinfp.pl '+self.options+' -ai '+str(self.ip)+' -p '+str(p)
        args = shlex.split(com_string) 
        self.result=subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
        self.parse(p)
```

The parse function then utilises result  stored in self.result to store output for that PORT. An aggregate of all the ports is what constitues a scan result for an IP.

Calling this code using 10 threads gives accurate o/p (when compared to nmap output). On giving 15 threads an occasional open port is missed. On giving 20 threads, more open ports are missed. On giving 50 threads many ports are missed.

P.S. - As a first timer, this code is very convoluted. Apologies to the puritans.

P.P.S. - Even a threaded port scan takes 15 minutes for an entire class C subnet with hardly 20 ports scanned. I was wondering if I should move this code to another language and use Python to only parse the results. Could somebody suggest me a language? 
Note -I am exploring Shell option as shown by S.Lott but manual processing is required before dumping it into file.

Comment: Why are you having threads running processes?  The OS runs multiple processes like this for you -- without you having to write a bunch of threads.

Comment: 1. Why don't you use an existing solution such as `nmap`? 2. An asynchronous solutions such as based on http://twistedmatrix.com might be more suitable than threads (to scan 255*64k ports fast) 3. `close_fds=True` wouldn't hurt if you are not on Windows. 4. The problem might not in the `subprocess` but in your scanner, try running it with GNU `parallel` http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/parallel and see if the errors persist. Here's python script https://gist.github.com/717467 from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287178/better-multithreaded-use-of-python-subprocess-popen-communicate

Comment: Actually the project envisages use of more than one scanner. So I have already used nmap as one of the tools. It works fine. For a 'second opinion', I used the scanner 'sinfp'. BTW for 10 threads also the ouput DOES NOT get mixed up. But as I increase the no. of threads, the o/p starts getting murkier. For 50 threads, some alive hosts are also dropped.

Comment: @RedBaron: Why mess with threads at all?  Why not use simple OS processes?

Comment: @S.Lott : Since I am a newbie to python, could you give an example?

Comment: @RedBaron: It's not a Python thing.  It's an OS/Shell thing.  Please read up on the `&` operator in the shell.  It will run multiple processes concurrently.  Concurrent Processes do not share I/O resources and do not have the same limitations as threads.  It's an OS feature, not a Python feature.  Why aren't you using OS multi-processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the shell

```
 for h in host1 host2 host3
 do
     scan $h >$h.scan &
 done
 cat *.scan >all.scan
```

This will scan the entire list of hosts all at the same time, each in a separate process.  No threads.

Each scan will produce a `.scan` file.  You can then cat all the `.scan` files into a massive `all.scan` file for further processing or whatever it is you're doing.

Comment: How do I retrieve the outputs(text strings) without mixing them?

Comment: @RedBaron: Use the shell.  It's quite straight-forward.  You collect each output into separate files and then merge the files with `cat`.  Please read up on the Linux OS.  All of this is well-documented in an "intro to the shell" book.

Comment: @S. Lott: This does not suffice for my cause.I guess I'll stick to python since the program works for limited number of threads. My original query was as to why the output gets jumbled for a large number of threads. Is it a possible limitation of spawning a process using Popen when using threads.

Comment: @RedBaron: "This does not suffice for my cause."?  In what way?  This works perfectly.  Can you be **specific** as to what's wrong with this?

Comment: @S.Lott : I didn't say anything was wrong with it. It is a gud idea and I am working on incorporating it within my program. Will try and compare results of your approach and already available code

Comment: @RedBaron: "This does not suffice for my cause."  "I didn't say anything was wrong with it."  First you said it didn't suffice.  Then you said nothing was wrong.  It's hard to help when you're not clear.

Comment: You said "This works perfectly", so I told you I didn't think anything was wriong with it. Anyways thanks for your pointers. When I said this did not suffice my cause all I meant was it is too simplistic since this needs to be called from a python program and would be passed maybe a list of 256 hosts AND 1000 ports (remember the scanner is per port), so the o/p file is per port not per host. Anyways I am working on a workaround. Thanks a million fr your time and I didn't mean to demean your help

Comment: #!/bin/bash
all_port=$1
line=$2
for port in `cat $all_port`
 do
 echo "`/usr/local/sinfp/bin/sinfp.pl -r1 -t1 -C -ai $line -p$port &`"
 done

Comment: I wrote this script and it works fine. BUT there is another strange problem. FOr some IPs I get "parallelized" eecution as S.Lott has said, while for others it looks like execution is still serialized(it takes lot of time)

Comment: BTW $1 is a file that (file.txt) that has a list of ports to scan while $2 is the IP address (e.g. - 172.16.12.2)

Comment: @RedBaron: "for others it looks like execution is still serialized(it takes lot of time) –"  Everything must be in parallel.  Random "serialized" is not possible.  Something else is wrong.  It could be that the connection is having a timeout.  Waiting for a timeout will take a long time.  You will need to do more accurate and complete logging.

Comment: @RedBaron: "too simplistic since this needs to be called from a python program and would be passed maybe a list of 256 hosts AND 1000 ports"  Update your question.  Use two loops.  `for h in $hosts; do; for p in $ports; do;`.

Comment: @S.Lott: Agreed that there will be a timeout but since all probes are sent in parallel won't the timeouts occur almost together? So after timeout, output of all probes should come simultaneosly. Here, however, after probe1's timeout output of probe1 comes and then probe2 is fired. I know this 'coz a temp pcap file is created in my working dir and it shows only one port as being scanned. The 'truly' parallel scan occurs for very few IPs while for the rest this 'serialized' version occurs. Any pointers?

Comment: @RedBaron: Since you're now asking about the Shell and Debian, please open a new question.  At this point, your comments have very little to do with your original question.

Comment: @S.Lott: Nevermind. Got it working. Thanks fr ur help. I think there's something wrong with tool itself since it bungles output in shell also. BTW Shell is a fast and non-messy way to parallelize

Comment: @RedBaron:  "BTW Shell is a fast and non-messy way to parallelize".  Exactly.  Start there first.  Write less code.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try it?

(Answer: No they will have their own pipe)

Comment: I tried it. Actually I tried by using a file object as stdout. The file name is different for different threads. It seemed to work fine. But for large number of threads, to me it seems the output was getting mixed up, since program was deviating from normal behaviour

Comment: If you are using *one* file object for standard out, then yes obviously the output will be mixed up. How could it be otherwise? If you use one file object per *process* then it obviously will *not* be mixed up. This is what the PIPE flag does, you'll get a handle on the stream of the stdout of the process. One handle per stdout stream.

Comment: The file objects are for different file for each thread. SO I don't think they shud get mixed up. Output starts getting mixed up as thread number is increased

Comment: AH. I was unclear: Are they different *files*? If they are I can't possibly see how the output would get mixed up.

Comment: Yes they are.... and output does get mixed. To be a bit more precise - I scanned a full subnet for some well known ports and stored result for each port and each IP in a different file. This result is in form of Text string showing whether port is closed and if not the OS match. Its fine for 10 threads or 20 threads with locking(shown above). But if I use 20 or 50 threads, some of open port files also show text associated withg closed ports. It is clear that either the tool or popen itself is not threadsafe. Using subprocess.PIPE as stdout also leads to same behaviour.

Comment: Do you have code which demonstrates this problem, because that sounds really weird.

Answer (score 0):

Use Perl instead of Python. The program (SinFP) is written in Perl, you can modify the code to suite your needs.